# erros in Ubuntu Terminal when deploying my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, rvm, omniauth

I have built a ruby on rails application using Ubuntu. My application is on github. Normally I transfer the latest developments from github to my website, www.mywebsite.com, by doing in Terminal:

```
cap production deploy:migrations
```

And everything works fine. I see in Terminal the progress of the transfer like:

```
* executing "rm -rf /var/www/apps/myapp/releases/20130720123042/public/assets &&\\\n        mkdir -p /var/www/apps/myapp/releases/20130720123042/public &&\\\n        mkdir -p /var/www/apps/myapp/shared/assets &&\\\n        ln -s /var/www/apps/myapp/shared/assets /var/www/apps/myapp/releases/20130720123042/public/assets"
    servers: ["92.51.243.6"]
    [92.51.243.6] executing command
    command finished in 626ms
  * executing `bundle:install'
  * executing "cd /var/www/apps/myapp/releases/20130720123042 && bundle install --gemfile /var/www/apps/myapp/releases/20130720123042/Gemfile --path /var/www/apps/myapp/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
    servers: ["92.51.243.6"]
    [92.51.243.6] executing command
    command finished in 1595ms
  * executing "chmod -R g+w /var/www/apps/myapp/releases/20130720123042"
    servers: ["92.51.243.6"]
    [92.51.243.6] executing command
    command finished in 645ms
```

Now the process doesn't complete as it used to and I get this message:

```
  * executing "cd /var/www/apps/myapp/releases/20130720123042 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
    servers: ["92.51.243.6"]
    [92.51.243.6] executing command
 ** [out :: 92.51.243.6] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: 92.51.243.6] Received wrong number of arguments. [nil]
 ** [out :: 92.51.243.6] /var/www/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/omniauth-1.1.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:136:in `initialize'


more stuff here like the line above..

failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ree-1.8.7-2012.02' -c 'cd /var/www/apps/myapp/releases/20130720123042 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile'" on 92.51.243.6
mypc@ubuntu:~/myapp$
```

Any idea how I can fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `initialize_on_precompile` set to true?

Comment: I searched for 'initialize_on_precompile' in my whole local project and couldn't find it. In my config/environments/production.rb I have 'config.assets.compile = false' and '# config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )' is commented out.

Comment: Can you run this on server and post result here? (probably need to update the dir) `cd /var/www/apps/myapp/releases/20130720123042 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile --trace`

Comment: When I run it I get the message: -bash: bundle: command not found. I might also add that as soon as I log into my server I get the message -bash: __rvm_add_to_path: command not found.

Comment: So I guess you have a problem with rvm installation (2nd) and bundler installation (1st). Maybe consider using Heroku in the beginning?

Comment: Ok, thanks. Current hosting company were working fine until now and their support has been good. All this trouble started happening when I attempted to restart my server-someone suggested it might deal with a Facebook problem I was having (which you helped me with, thanks). An idea how I can get bundler and rvm working again?

Comment: By restart the server you mean the VPS machine? COuld you dig out the logs from restart, maybe there will be some clue?

Comment: Sorry, had to go out. When I do [root@myapp ~]# sudo service httpd restart I get
'Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: [Sat Jul 20 16:55:53 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts'

Comment: So there's a problem with config. I wonder how it could be connected to restart.

Comment: the error you show is in https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/v1.1.2/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb#L136 - it is not rvm related, please show whole deploy log and configuration, it is important to see it all.